# Google Map Api v3 and XML feed

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3

I have a XML file like this :

```
<datas>
<title>AAA</title>
<lat>111</lat>
<lng>5454</lng>
</datas>
<datas>
<title>BBB</title>
<lat>112121</lat>
<lng>544254</lng>
</datas>
```

....

Example :
Here is a "real" example :

```
<productFeed>
<Deal>
<Deal_ID>201090531</Deal_ID>
<Price>9.50</Price>
<Destination_Name>Green River</Destination_Name>
<Latitude>38.989869999999996</Latitude>
<Longitude>-110.13261</Longitude>
<Country_Name>United States of America</Country_Name>
</Deal>
</productFeed>
```

The initialize function :

```
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.82672127366604,-118.916015625),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  downloadUrl("test.xml", function(doc) {
      var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
      var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Deal");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Latitude"));
        var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Longitude"));
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        var html = markers[i].getAttribute("Deal_ID");
        var label = markers[i].getAttribute("Price");
        var marker = createMarker(latlng,label,html);
        }
      });
    }
```

Is Google Map API able to read it and display it on a map ?
If so, how ?

I tried adapt this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers?hl=en but does not work.

Thanks for your help.
Dominique

Comment: what is "rad"?  Is that supposed to be "read"?  Those numbers are not valid latitude and longitudes (at lease in Google Maps standard coordinate system),  are they just random numbers or do they need to be converted to [WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGS84)?

Comment: Yes, read. Lat and lng are exemples, not true data. Just for explain the structure of the xml file.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put your XML in the format your code is expecting?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 does not contain any XML parsing.  But you can parse XML with javascript and display the results on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map.

Your code currently parses XML of this format:

```
 <Deal Latitude="38.989869999999996" Longitude="-110.13261" Deal_ID="201090531" Price="9.50" />
```

function from geoxml3 that returns the text content of an element (like `<lat>`):

```
//nodeValue: Extract the text value of a DOM node, with leading and trailing whitespace trimmed
geoXML3.nodeValue = function(node, defVal) {
  var retStr="";
  if (!node) {
    return (typeof defVal === 'undefined' || defVal === null) ? '' : defVal;
  }
   if(node.nodeType==3||node.nodeType==4||node.nodeType==2){
      retStr+=node.nodeValue;
   }else if(node.nodeType==1||node.nodeType==9||node.nodeType==11){
      for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;++i){
         retStr+=arguments.callee(node.childNodes[i]);
      }
   }
   return retStr;
};
```

[relevant discussion from the Google Maps Javascript API v2 group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/google-maps-api/parse%2420XML%2420%3Clatitude%3E/google-maps-api/CUbAQf2sXiE/Vp83pAdW9BcJ) (but v3 doesn't have the GXml functionality).

[another relevant discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/google-maps-api/parse%2420XML%2420%3Clatitude%3E/google-maps-api/hDWdHpqhAXI/MaGxG4ZXpWAJ)

Comment: OK. Any exemple of a map displaying markers from a XML file like mine ?

Comment: I know I have seen them, couldn't find any easily.  Your format is similar to (but not identical to) some RSS/atom feeds.  The 3rd party KML parser [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) contains code to parse out the contents of an XML element [nodeValue](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/polys/geoxml3.js), added to the answer.

Comment: If you had posted XML that made sense to parse, I might have done that.  Why don't you give it a shot and ask more specific questions when/if you run into trouble.

Comment: Here is a "real" example (I can't answer, just make comments):

<productFeed>
<Deal>
<Deal_ID>201090531</Deal_ID>
<Price>9.50</Price>
<Destination_Name>Green River</Destination_Name>
<Latitude>38.989869999999996</Latitude>
<Longitude>-110.13261</Longitude>
<Country_Name>United States of America</Country_Name>
</Deal>
</productFeed>

Comment: Please add that to your question.  What does your code look like to parse it?

Comment: Added, with function.

Comment: I do not really understand how pass from my current xml file to format <Deal Latitude="...> ...

Comment: [example from recent question that uses jquery to parse xml similar to yours (`<lat>` instead of `<Latitude`, `<lng>` instead of `<Longitude>`)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_jquery_multipleMarkersFromXmlA.html)